# proving a simple graph can be drawn by Euler second law or any other law

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was given a question that says

> Draw a simple graph with 5 vertices of degree 0, 1, 2, 2, 3 if they exist, otherwise briefly explain why no such graph exist.

However according to `euler second law` it says

> In any graph, the number of vertices which have odd degree is even

I believe, this means that any type of graph can be drawn as long as `the number of vertices which have odd degree is even`

which is exactly the case for the question above.

and `simple graph` is

> a graph which has neither loops nor parallel edges

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to draw them despite satisfying the `euler second law`

**EDIT** :

[Graph Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJGtu.jpg)

I managed to figure out with the help of the community but i would like to ask what is the way to exactly identify  if a certain number of vertices can be drawn.

Comment: Have you *tried drawing* it yet?  You have a vertex of degree zero.  Great, don't put any edges on it.  You have a vertex of degree three, so it must have an edge from it to all of the other vertices except the vertex of degree zero.  Sure, no problem yet.  Now you need two of the remaining vertices to have degree two and the other to have degree one.  Can you see how you can accomplish that by drawing one more edge somewhere?

Comment: Sometimes, instead of trying to disprove something... if it is not immediately obvious how to disprove it, you should try to *prove* it instead.

Comment: For the record, $G$ is a simple graph $\implies$ the degree sequence of $G$ has an even number of odd numbers.   **THE CONVERSE IS NOT TRUE** (*most converses you encounter are not true*).  It is not true that "If a sequence has an even number of odd numbers then there is a simple graph with that degree sequence."  For example, there is no simple graph with the degree sequence $6,0,0,0,0$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Guess i can't just take one's law and try to prove the other. Seems like the way is to identify degree by degree if they can be drawn

Answer (score 3):

Take the graph with vertices $A,B,C,D,E$ and edges $AB,AC,AD,BC$.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Create a graph with $5$ vertices, and the edges given as above.

Comment: yes. I somehow managed to figure how to draw the simple graph, however, i'm more curious is there any formula that allow us to identify if a particular number of vertices of particular number of degree can be drawn? There seems to be no method of identification on my notes

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan See the Havel-Hakimi or Erdos-Gallai theorems.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe, this means that any type of graph can be drawn as long as the number of vertices which have odd degree is even

Technically, that's not what the theorem states. The theorem states:

> **If** the graph can be drawn, **then** the number of vertices with odd degree is even.

This is ***not at all the same as***

> **If** the number of vertices with odd degree is even, **then** the graph can be drawn.

For example, you cannot draw a simple graph with vertices of degree $0,0,0,1,3$.

---

That said, in your case, you **can** draw such a graph. Simply draw 5 points, and make one of them a vertex of degree $3$ while making sure that one other has degree $0$. What do you get? Which other edge do you need to make?

Comment: I managed to figure out how to draw but if i get such question like that with more vertices and more degree, is there any formula or law i can use to prove to show that such simple graph can be drawn?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan Not that I know of. For example, you can show that $0,0,2$ is impossible because the third vertex needs to be connected to something but not the first and not the second vertex, which is a contradiction. But this doesn't always work...